# Get resource name of the string if i know the view's name

Tags: android, android-resources

I have a TextView

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/str_text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

If i have this..

```
TextView txt = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

How can i get this

```
"str_text"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You can go from ID to the value, but not the reverse. To make it more clear why not, imagine if you had multiple string resources with the same value.

The resource ID isn't stored after inflating the View.

Comment: And i can get the entry point of this string?? public static final int str_text=0x7f040005;

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: i want know if i can get this value **0x7f040005** its in the class R... sorry by my english

Comment: `R.string.str_text` will be that value. However, as stated, you can't determine that at runtime from an inflated view.